# jQuery val is undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, undefined

I have this code:

```
<input type="hidden" id="editorTitle" name="title" value="home">
<textarea name="text" id="editorText"></textarea>
```

But when i write `$('#editorTitle').val()` and `$('#editorText').html()`, `$('#editorTitle').val()` is 'undefined' and `$('#editorText').html()` is empty?

What is wrong?

---

Edit:

Here is my full code:

```
function openEditor() {
    $("#editor").show().animate({ width: 965, height: 380 }, 1500);
    $("#editor textarea").show();
}

function closeEditor() {
    $("#editor").animate({ width: 985, height: 1 }, 1500, function () {
        $("#editor").hide();
        $("#editor textarea").hide();
    });
}

function setedit() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "engine.php",
        data: "title=" + $('#editorTitle').attr('value') + "&text=" + $('#editorText').html(),
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#mainField').html('<img src="data/images/loader.gif" alt="Loading...">');
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
            closeEditor();
            search();
        }
    });
}
function search() {
    $('#title').val($('#search').val());

    $.get('engine.php?search=' + $('#search').val(), function (data) {
        $('#mainField').html(data);
    });

    $.get('engine.php?raw=true&search=' + $('#search').val(), function (data2) {
        $('#editorText').html(data2);
    });

    $.get('engine.php?title=true&search=' + $('#search').val(), function (data2) {
        $('#h1').html(data2); // Row 152
        $('#editorTitle').html(data2);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ready").html('Document ready at ' + event.timeStamp);
});
```

But what is wrong?!?!

Comment: Are you using $('#editorTitle').val() and $('#editorText').html() in jQuery ready event/after the elements are available in DOM?

Comment: Nothing wrong in your code. You need to provide more context. Test case at http://jsfiddle.net/heYJh/

Comment: editorText is empty because there's nothing in the textarea. make sure you are doing the jQuery onDomReady

Comment: Is `.val()` still undefined if you close the `input` tag?  Also, shouldn't `html()` be empty in this case?  I thought it returned inner child elements, and the `textarea` tag has none.  Or am I mistaken?

Comment: You might have computed the value before browser has parsed the elements, so use the code after ready function :
$(document).ready(function(){})

Comment: Thanks for the edit. How does your code get called? The $(document).ready() doesn't do anything related to the setEditor() in which the problem occurs. I gather that the undefined and empty values occur in the POST-request URL, not as a result of the search().

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**You probably included your JavaScript *before* the HTML: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ArondeParon/zwbbp/).**

You should either execute your JavaScript when the window loads (or better, when the DOM is fully loaded), or you should include your JavaScript *after* your HTML: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ArondeParon/3QeSe/).

Comment: You made my day! I was to get the value on change action using $(this) context and almost I was getting mad until I saw your solution. Thx.

Answer (score 13):

You should call the events **after the document is ready**, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Your code
});
```

This is because you are trying to manipulate elements before they are rendered by the browser.

So, in the case you posted it should look something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var editorTitle = $('#editorTitle').val();
  var editorText = $('#editorText').html();
});
```

Hope it helps.

*Tips: always save your jQuery object in a variable for later use and only code that really need to run after the document have loaded should go inside the ready() function.*

Answer (score 6):

This is stupid but for future reference. 
I did put all my code in:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //your jQuery function
});
```

But still it wasn't working and it was returning `undefined` value. 
I check my HTML DOM

```
<input id="username" placeholder="Username"></input>
```

and I realised that I was referencing it wrong in jQuery:

```
var user_name = $('#user_name').val();
```

Making it:

```
var user_name = $('#username').val();
```

solved my problem.

So it's always better to check your previous code.

Answer (score 4):

could it be that you forgot to load it in the document ready function?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //your jQuery function
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I just ran across this myself yesterday on a project I was working on.  I'm my specific case, it was not exactly what the input was named, but *how* the ID was named.

```
<input id="user_info[1][last_name]" ..... />
var last_name = $("#user_info[1][last_name]").val() // returned undefined
```

Removing the brackets solved the issue:

```
<input id="user_info1_last_name" ..... />
var last_name = $("#user_info1_last_name").val() // returned "MyLastNameValue"
```

Anyway, probably a no brainer for some people, but in case this helps anyone else... there you go!

:-)
- Drew

Answer (score 1):

you may forgot to wrap your object with `$()`

```
  var tableChild = children[i];
  tableChild.val("my Value");// this is wrong
```

and the ccorrect one is

```
$(tableChild).val("my Value");// this is correct
```

Answer (score 0):

try: `$('#editorTitle').attr('value')` ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had 2 functions with same name.