# jQuery, bootstrap: input.val() is undefined, even though jsfiddle works fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a jsfiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/hhimanshu/ukYek/

This works fine on jsfiddle, but when I do the same in my app, firebug says

```
input.val() is undefined

$('#create-playlist-button').attr('disabled',input.val().length==0);
```

I did some googling and found a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006045/jquery-val-is-undefined)

**update**
Fiddle updated - http://jsfiddle.net/hhimanshu/ukYek/4/ (The problem is stil the same)

**Question**
- How do I fix this issue, when the javascript is already loaded and form segment is loaded little late with ajax event?

Comment: Hiya, jsfiddle doesn't seem to be valid as I cannot see `new-list` id in html DOM?

Comment: Like @Tats_innit said, you're using the selector `$('#new-list :input');` but your form id is `new-playlist`. Use  `$('#new-playlist :input');` instead.

Comment: also there is no need for $(input) since input is already a jQuery object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an updated version of your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vwvm2/1/

changes

1) put id on html input text

2) use $(this) which is that input field